# symfony 2.3 Can't integrate FosUserBundle library

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.3

I'm trying to use the Fosuser library in my symfony project for authentication system on windows environment. I followed the[documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.3.x/Resources/doc/index.md) and this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvLUvOaW_XY).
 After the sixth step I try to execute `app/console router:debug` but I get this error:

```
 [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]   
 There is no extension able to load the configuration for "fos_user" (in C:\  
 wamp\www\new_project\app/config\config.yml). Looked for namespace "  
 fos_user", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer",  
 "assetic", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "user", "acme_demo", "web  
_profiler", "sensio_distribution"
```

and this is my app/config.yml:

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml } 

framework:
#esi:             ~
#translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
translator: ~
secret:          "%secret%"
router:
    resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
    strict_requirements: ~
form:            ~
csrf_protection: ~
validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
    #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
default_locale:  "%locale%"
trusted_proxies: ~
session:         ~
fragments:       ~
http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
use_controller: false
bundles:        [ ]
#java: /usr/bin/java
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    #closure:
    #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
    #yui_css:
    #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

 # Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   "%database_driver%"
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
    # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
    #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
    #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
    #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
    #   3. Uncomment next line:
    #     path:     "%database_path%"

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    auto_mapping: true

  # Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
transport: "%mailer_transport%"
host:      "%mailer_host%"
username:  "%mailer_user%"
password:  "%mailer_password%"
spool:     { type: memory }

# Fos_user Configuration
fos_user:
db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
firewall_name: main
user_class: User\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Added the bundle in your AppKernel.php?

Comment: You need to add the bundle in your AppKernel.php  add this in registerBundles method new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),

Comment: @Gahda Salem Please, answer your question with the solution and accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

As they have mentioned in the comments, I have made a mistake by not adding the bundle in my `AppKernel.php`. Actually I added it and comment it because I haven't complete the library installation process.
When I added this line in the `AppKernel.php` :
`new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle()`
the problem was resolved.